# How do I release a Drupal Distribution

Tags: distributions

I have been developing a site and I feel that it would work really well as a Drupal distribution. I have no idea about how to create one, but I am familiar with drush make, install profiles etc. What is a Drupal distribution and how do I release one? What are the main benefits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Packaging a distribution on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/642116)

**Here are the steps:**

1. Assemble the pre-requisites
2. Create a Drush Make file
3. Convert to a Drupal.org-specific Drush Make file
4. Build and verify it works
5. Commit your code to Git
6. Release your code on Drupal.org
7. Maintain your distribution

Another great tutorial [How to Write a Drupal 7 Installation Profile](http://www.isaacsukin.com/news/2011/01/10/how-write-drupal-7-installation-profile)

Also there is [Profiler Builder](http://drupal.org/project/profiler_builder) module.

> Profiler Builder is a module for automating the creation of
>   installation profiles and distributions. It has support for the
>   Profiler installation profile simplifier library but is able to run
>   independent of it (1.0-RC4+). This module creates a downloadable tar
>   package that gives you a well made installation profile and associated
>   drush make file based on the site its installed on.

Comment: Another useful link [“So You Want to Build a Drupal Product…”](http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/so-you-want-to-build-a-drupal-product/)

Comment: How do you do the 'release your code on Drupal.org' bit?